# How can I map with modelmapper some conditions?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, dto, modelmapper

I have some `Game` entity that I want to map in `GameDto`. In `Game` I have another `Game` field `basedOn`. In `GameDto` I have `basedOnName`, `basedOnId` and `basedOnCheckBox` fields.

Can I somehow map `basedOnCheckBox` to true in case of `Game` has `basedOn != null` or in GameDto `basedOnName/Id != null`?

Now my code for this operation:

```
if(gameDto.getBaseOnName() != null) {
      gameDto.setBaseOnCheckBox(true);
  }
```

I'm usind `modelMapper v.3.1.0`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like found an answer how to do it:

```
Converter<Game, Boolean> notNullFieldToBoolean = c -> c.getSource() != null;
...
mapper.using(notNullFieldToBoolean).map(Game::getBaseOn, GameDto::setBaseOnCheckBox);
...
```